# how to overcome error showing on clicking a video link from my own webpage

Tags: html, css

how to embed a Youtube video on a personal webpage when it is showing error as-:

it is restricted from playback on certain sites

Answer (score 0):

You can't. There are settings that only allow some videos to be embedded in monetized platforms. [image: See Here]